# Why DenseNet implementation in pytorch has batch normalization and ReLU at the end?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I'm using pretrained DenseNet model from pytorch (https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_densenet/)
Looking at it's code I noticed that since the first submission it has additional batch normalization after final denseblock - line 176:

```
self.features.add_module('norm5', nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features))
```

and ReLU in the forward pass (line 193). Both of those I don't see in original paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf). Does anyone know if I'm missing something here?

Edit: I can see that original implementation also has it (https://github.com/liuzhuang13/DenseNet/blob/master/models/densenet.lua). But the question still remains, as I can't see this in the paper.

Comment: The history of that file is [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/commits/master/torchvision/models/densenet.py). I didn't see any obvious reference to this change, but didn't dig through it. I assume that the authors used it in the original implementation and just forgot to mention it in the paper, so the PyTorch implementation matched the original implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, as I wrote in edit, I can even see the same layers in the original implementation. To be honest that's weird to me that they'd just forget. This is quite relevant when using DenseNet for example for feature extraction.

Comment: I doubt you'll get a better answer here; you could try emailing the authors, but I'm very skeptical there'd be any answer better than either (a) "we forgot to include it in the paper" or, less likely, (b) "we added this after the final conference deadline for changes." I don't know whether you've done this or not, but writing papers is an unfortunately error-prone task.